# Pegando categoria de uma tabela em Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Pessoal tenho uma tabela de cadastro de produtos e nela eu tenho categorias:

```
$consulta = mysql_query('select categoria from produtos order by categoria');
 while ($var=mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
    {
        echo "<a href='editar.php?categoria=$var[categoria]'>$var[categoria]</a><br><br>";
    }
```

O problema é que ele me traz assim:

```
-Bebidas
-Bebidas
-Higiene e Limpeza
-Higiene e Limpeza
-Mercearia
-Padaria e Confeitaria
```

Como deixar apenas um titulo da Categoria e não duplicado como esta ficando.
Desde ja agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessário somente agrupar pelo campo `categoria`

#### SQL de Pesquisa

```
$consulta = mysql_query('select categoria from produtos group by categoria order by categoria');
```

Comment: Obrigado Marlon funcionou perfeitamente :)

Comment: @kidFerreira, marca a resposta como correta ;)